# Customizing Sharepoint 2010 v4.master

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to customize v4.master in markup so that certain areas (Libraries, Discussion for instance) would not be visible. I tried deleting the placeholder and that didn't work. How can I hide certain areas of that master page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are clean master page it's name "**Starter Master Page**" .It's better to start customize Starter Master page instead of v4.Master

 You can download it and learn more from the following link 
[Starter Master Pages for SharePoint 2010](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/)